# HTTP POST request with Google's C++ Native Client

Tags: web-applications, google-nativeclient

How would one perform a HTTP POST request with Google's C++ Native Client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question was asked a long time ago, but just in case anyone else is wondering the same thing:

You can use [pp::URLRequstInfo::SetMethod](https://developers.google.com/native-client/peppercpp/classpp_1_1_u_r_l_request_info.html#abf4024d196a5139dbca2e95b9ab9bdb6) to do a POST request.

And you can add data to the post using [pp::URLRequestInfo::AppendDataToBody](https://developers.google.com/native-client/peppercpp/classpp_1_1_u_r_l_request_info.html#ab16f2efba1f2ddc434e2fc860dcbe90), [pp::URLRequestInfo::AppendFileRangeToBody](https://developers.google.com/native-client/peppercpp/classpp_1_1_u_r_l_request_info.html#af19afd7e5849e68497f1e4f4b7400995) or [pp::URLRequestInfo::AppendFileToBody](https://developers.google.com/native-client/peppercpp/classpp_1_1_u_r_l_request_info.html#a1ae72c8ac65a6cd6c174c8df238038fd).

See an example of using URLLoader class here:
https://developers.google.com/native-client/devguide/coding/URLLoading