# sending a POST request with Google's C++ native client

Tags: c++, rest, google-nativeclient

Can someone give an example of how to send a POST request with Google's C++ native client? The question has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6935585/http-post-request-with-googles-c-native-client), but Google's documentation is not very helpful (and in some cases non-existent). And yes, I have been scouring github for help, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at the NativeClient SDK's examples?

In the nacl_sdk\pepper_\examples\api\url_loader folder you'll find an example of how to use the URLLoader.